# sample means with distributions that almost have a true mean

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence

The Cauchy distribution, $\frac 1 {\pi(1+x^2)}$, has no mean. The distribution of the sample mean $\bar X$ is the original Cauchy distribution so you end up where you started, no matter how many samples you take. This is in contract to the "usual" behavior where standard deviation of the sample mean scales as $\frac 1 {\sqrt N}$.

But the Cauchy distribution is *close*. Changing the distribution to $\frac C {(1+|x|^{2+\epsilon})}$ for any small $\epsilon>0$ gives X a true mean of zero which $\bar X$ converges to.

But what about a *smaller* change? $X $~$ \frac C {1+x^{2}ln|x|}$. For large *x*, the 1 on the denominator becomes irrelevant: $\int \frac {Cx} {1+x^{2}ln|x|} \approx \int \frac {Cx} {x^{2}ln|x|} = C ln(ln(x)) + (const),\ \ x >>0$. This grows much more slowly than $ln(x)$ but it still diverges, and we have no mean. But will the sample mean converge for this modified $X$? Convergence in this case would mean that the sample mean gets within a given $\epsilon$  of zero with probability 1 as $N$ goes to infinity.